# How to use Blazor components from namespace sharing the same prefix

Tags: c#, namespaces, blazor

My app lives in namespace "App.Proj.Ui" while components in "Proj.Components", as the effect I cannot reference them.

- putting `@using global::Proj.Components` both in "_Imports.razor" and/or in given page of the main app results in info, that referenced components from my components project is not recognized,
- using full name `<Proj.Components.MyComponentA...` gives the same result
- and adding "global::" to the tag turns this into html tag (lower case at the beginning)

So, is there a way to reference components from a project with prefix name which is used also in main app name (in this example it is "Proj")?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft documentation:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#:~:text=The%20global%3A%3A%20qualification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#:%7E:text=The%20global%3A%3A%20qualification).

global:: is not supported.

but you main issue is the conflict with Proj which is present in two different namespaces not at the same level.

It won't work and you have to change it.